# Set hash object value by location stored as array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Im not sure how to access the original json at a variable height.

```
    var json = {
                 "parent": {
                             "child": "foo"
                           }
                };


    function set_json_value(loc,value){
      var curr_json_item = json;
      for(var i = 0; i < loc.length - 1;i++){
        curr_json_item = curr_json_item[loc[i]];
      }
      curr_json_item = value;
      console.log(json);
     }

    set_json_value(["parent","child"],"bar");
```

The value at parent->child remains as "foo" and json is unchanged.

Comment: You are just overwriting a variable (`cur_json_item`) but not changing any of its properties. And in the end, you assign `value` to it anyway, everything you did before is nuts then.

Comment: Yeah, Im not sure how to make curr_json_item be a reference to a child hash tree of json instead of just a 1d hash at that level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just change the value of your variable but you don't update the object itself by modifying a property. I guess you wanted something like this:

```
function set_json_value(loc,value){
   // todo: make sure loc is not empty here

   var curr_json_item = json;
   for(var i = 0; i < loc.length - 1;i++){
     curr_json_item = curr_json_item[loc[i]];
   }
   curr_json_item[loc[loc.length-1]] = value;
   console.log(json);
}
```

Also, you don't pass "json" as a parameter, but work with the global variable itself, I would change this as well.

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this it creates a new element called "child" at the same level as "parent".

Comment: I changed the answer, saw a mistake there, must be `i < loc.length - 1` of course